# Identifying the highest peak, and return the values that is low to the right and left of highest peak, by keeping the highest peak as reference

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have data where I need to return the values that are low by keeping the highest value or peak as a reference, there are many peaks, I need to return the lows of each peak and store them to a variable.

Sample data:

```
A=['6452', '6444', '6452', '6456', '6455', '6465', '6456', '6442', '6449', '6452', '6455', '6465', '6463', '6452', '6459', '6470', '6456', '6435', '6438', '6441', '6438', '6448', '6451', '6439', '6449', '6472', '6483', '6503', '6531', '6524', '6523', '6538', '6550', '6534', '6537', '6554', '6540', '6538', '6553', '6558', '6568', '6588', '6609', '6615', '6616', '6625', '6628', '6633', '6628', '6612', '6605', '6605', '6599', '6587', '6588', '6589', '6584', '6592', '6592', '6571', '6555', '6551', '6533', '6521', '6517', '6502', '6493', '6476', '6473', '6469', '6455', '6463', '6462', '6438', '6424', '6428', '6417', '6400', '6404', '6398', '6398', '6417', '6425', '6422', '6429', '6448', '6435', '6424', '6434', '6439', '6431', '6429', '6418', '6407', '6412', '6415', '6407', '6412', '6424', '6415', '6403', '6417', '6425', '6424', '6425', '6428', '6427', '6432', '6455', '6442', '6420', '6446', '6503', '6558', '6654', '6748', '6841', '6945', '7053', '7160', '7229', '7237', '7150', '7062', '7025', '6882', '6657', '6493', '6391', '6278', '6156', '6083', '6076', '6081', '6091', '6115', '6145', '6189', '6234', '6282', '6298', '6323', '6370', '6393', '6408', '6429', '6427', '6431', '6452', '6454', '6456', '6465', '6461', '6456', '6472', '6487', '6493', '6493', '6509', '6500', '6496', '6497', '6487', '6472', '6480', '6496', '6489', '6490', '6506', '6506', '6492', '6507', '6517', '6507', '6485', '6495', '6496', '6500', '6509', '6502', '6492', '6510', '6530', '6533', '6545', '6545', '6530', '6526', '6533', '6536', '6527', '6533', '6531', '6527', '6529', '6536', '6538', '6554', '6561', '6555', '6553', '6567', '6574', '6570', '6572', '6581', '6578', '6582', '6608', '6613', '6616', '6625', '6643', '6643', '6652', '6662', '6662', '6653', '6670', '6684', '6686', '6700', '6714', '6714', '6737', '6759', '6761', '6768', '6778', '6786', '6785', '6785', '6792', '6786', '6779', '6790', '6807', '6813', '6823', '6819', '6812', '6826', '6828', '6830', '6833', '6836', '6816', '6799', '6806', '6821', '6813', '6793', '6800', '6793', '6796', '6807', '6787', '6770', '6773', '6753', '6737', '6728', '6722', '6703', '6686', '6670', '6639', '6618', '6618', '6609', '6594', '6585', '6571', '6547', '6543', '6543', '6543', '6514', '6512', '6523', '6514', '6492', '6485', '6482', '6487', '6482', '6473', '6492', '6506', '6489', '6473', '6476', '6478', '6475', '6480', '6483', '6461', '6452', '6465', '6463', '6463', '6463', '6466', '6461', '6459', '6473', '6463', '6454', '6462', '6462', '6445', '6449', '6469', '6470', '6475', '6473', '6469', '6475', '6486', '6483', '6486', '6497', '6499', '6495', '6502', '6495', '6487', '6483', '6490', '6493', '6486', '6497', '6489', '6473', '6483', '6514', '6510', '6497', '6503', '6510', '6521', '6503', '6496', '6489', '6490', '6497', '6492', '6485', '6495', '6490', '6490', '6497', '6504', '6493', '6487', '6506', '6507', '6496', '6499', '6497', '6492', '6506', '6502', '6493', '6502', '6510', '6506', '6502', '6512', '6519', '6502', '6504', '6526', '6507', '6504', '6517', '6519', '6506', '6513', '6514', '6502', '6509', '6516', '6503', '6506', '6516', '6514', '6500', '6503', '6513', '6521', '6524', '6526', '6509', '6523', '6530', '6524', '6524', '6534', '6524', '6517', '6536', '6544', '6540', '6529', '6547', '6553', '6536', '6543', '6540', '6527', '6540', '6540', '6526', '6529', '6533', '6537', '6523', '6533', '6541', '6531', '6540', '6550', '6543', '6537', '6548', '6548', '6548', '6564', '6561', '6560', '6557', '6553', '6547', '6548', '6553', '6554', '6554', '6555', '6558', '6551', '6557', '6574', '6565', '6561', '6564', '6558', '6551', '6550', '6554', '6554', '6547', '6555', '6544', '6555', '6562', '6548', '6545', '6558', '6554', '6545', '6545', '6545', '6541', '6560', '6579', '6575', '6577', '6587', '6589', '6599', '6628', '6636', '6623', '6623', '6628', '6623', '6628', '6646', '6654', '6653', '6660', '6667', '6669', '6676', '6680', '6677', '6679', '6684', '6676', '6664', '6656', '6657', '6646', '6659', '6669', '6663', '6645', '6640', '6625', '6606', '6606', '6599', '6572', '6553', '6545', '6543', '6533', '6533', '6534', '6516', '6516', '6541', '6521', '6492', '6493', '6490', '6482', '6479', '6478', '6489', '6483', '6487', '6495', '6500', '6507', '6510', '6493', '6495', '6495', '6482', '6476', '6485', '6478', '6480', '6500', '6499', '6478', '6500', '6510', '6513', '6512', '6521', '6504', '6492', '6495', '6503', '6493', '6509', '6495', '6475', '6485', '6529', '6577', '6664', '6759', '6845', '6950', '7062', '7171', '7264', '7288', '7215', '7128', '7114', '7032', '6814', '6618', '6512', '6410', '6278', '6190', '6183', '6183', '6180', '6186', '6212', '6236', '6294', '6340', '6354', '6387', '6434', '6456', '6492', '6509', '6509', '6516', '6540', '6560', '6567', '6560', '6553', '6541', '6564', '6582', '6577', '6568', '6579', '6591', '6574', '6558', '6561', '6551', '6541', '6547', '6554', '6558', '6574', '6575', '6577', '6578', '6594', '6589', '6594', '6601', '6596', '6579', '6601', '6606', '6599', '6611', '6635', '6625', '6611', '6623', '6635', '6622', '6632', '6628', '6601', '6605', '6622', '6623', '6628', '6628', '6632', '6636', '6649', '6652', '6654', '6656', '6663', '6654', '6652', '6653', '6646', '6652', '6671', '6679', '6684', '6703', '6704', '6712', '6720', '6746', '6770', '6749', '6752', '6753', '6744', '6746', '6775', '6783', '6787', '6803', '6817', '6826', '6834', '6844', '6843', '6853', '6874', '6867', '6860', '6847', '6853', '6861', '6872', '6875', '6878', '6874', '6889', '6878', '6875', '6879', '6888', '6885', '6895', '6894', '6881', '6878', '6891', '6877', '6860', '6854', '6840', '6824', '6820', '6812', '6793', '6763', '6758', '6748', '6742', '6738', '6720', '6669', '6649', '6646', '6632', '6619', '6619', '6608', '6588', '6567', '6577', '6574', '6564', '6561', '6554', '6536', '6534', '6519', '6517', '6526', '6510', '6497', '6516', '6521', '6516', '6513', '6514', '6497', '6504', '6531', '6533', '6516', '6510', '6523', '6521', '6504', '6495', '6487', '6499', '6504', '6480', '6475', '6493', '6503', '6490', '6487', '6487', '6493', '6495', '6512', '6503', '6476', '6482', '6496', '6502', '6502', '6504', '6500', '6503', '6496', '6506', '6487', '6490', '6500', '6486', '6486', '6510', '6509', '6499', '6504', '6510', '6490', '6495', '6504', '6504', '6500', '6507', '6506', '6497', '6503', '6512', '6495', '6514', '6533', '6517', '6502', '6509', '6493', '6496', '6509', '6504', '6500', '6519', '6510', '6482', '6468', '6472', '6465', '6459', '6473', '6479', '6452', '6456', '6463', '6462', '6472', '6478', '6485', '6476', '6492', '6497', '6478', '6475', '6493', '6490', '6495', '6507', '6507', '6503', '6492', '6469', '6452', '6451', '6465', '6472', '6456', '6448', '6441', '6438', '6462', '6476', '6459', '6472', '6493', '6480', '6473', '6478', '6469', '6463', '6465', '6469', '6466', '6456', '6449', '6451', '6434', '6438', '6451', '6444', '6449', '6449', '6437', '6442', '6452', '6439', '6442', '6445', '6429', '6425', '6431', '6437', '6432', '6418', '6421', '6422', '6418', '6428', '6445', '6439', '6441', '6441', '6427', '6432', '6441', '6444', '6441', '6438', '6422', '6418', '6415', '6418', '6404', '6415', '6434', '6429', '6414', '6405', '6403', '6407', '6421', '6431', '6415', '6429', '6432', '6428', '6446', '6469', '6469', '6466', '6489', '6497', '6479', '6497', '6500', '6483', '6489', '6489', '6513', '6530', '6536', '6530', '6530', '6541', '6531', '6537', '6544', '6543', '6547', '6541', '6540', '6533', '6520', '6547', '6577', '6574', '6557', '6533', '6520', '6521', '6502', '6476', '6441', '6425', '6414', '6393', '6374', '6364', '6349', '6352', '6360', '6356', '6343', '6357', '6362', '6343', '6349', '6369', '6337', '6333', '6346', '6350', '6345', '6356', '6349', '6321', '6309', '6336', '6325', '6319', '6332', '6336', '6335', '6340', '6340', '6349', '6369', '6376', '6356', '6339', '6337', '6340', '6328', '6318', '6313', '6308', '6304', '6326', '6308', '6289', '6304', '6340', '6369', '6410', '6495', '6582', '6666', '6770', '6881', '6981', '7059', '7024', '6920', '6913', '6919', '6756', '6550', '6437', '6340', '6237', '6146', '6105', '6087', '6079', '6079', '6071', '6091', '6161', '6190', '6197', '6221', '6246', '6284', '6339', '6367', '6377', '6388', '6408', '6412', '6418', '6432', '6444', '6424', '6429', '6459', '6441', '6452', '6463', '6452', '6461', '6485', '6499', '6473', '6455', '6462', '6485', '6493', '6496', '6492', '6473', '6480', '6496', '6479', '6476', '6482', '6468', '6472', '6489', '6502', '6493', '6514', '6533', '6534', '6543', '6547', '6547', '6553', '6557', '6536', '6516', '6523', '6513', '6500', '6527', '6558', '6544', '6550', '6554', '6568', '6579', '6604', '6594', '6560', '6571', '6579', '6555', '6537', '6553', '6571', '6578', '6578', '6587', '6582', '6599', '6622', '6622', '6611', '6619', '6637', '6640', '6646', '6662', '6662', '6681', '6698', '6704', '6704', '6728', '6725', '6718', '6717', '6729', '6738', '6745', '6734', '6742', '6745', '6755', '6761', '6763', '6772', '6770', '6768', '6768', '6758', '6755', '6759', '6766', '6758', '6756', '6755', '6751', '6749', '6739', '6732', '6745', '6737', '6729', '6708', '6697', '6695', '6686', '6670', '6653', '6646', '6637', '6623', '6601', '6584', '6567', '6575', '6558', '6530', '6524', '6533', '6513', '6486', '6470', '6468', '6442', '6439', '6446', '6427', '6418', '6415', '6397', '6414', '6427', '6428', '6417', '6424', '6438', '6435', '6438', '6449', '6438', '6434', '6444', '6448', '6431', '6425', '6424', '6421', '6429', '6439', '6429', '6432', '6444', '6449', '6442', '6448', '6456', '6439', '6431', '6432', '6421', '6431', '6432', '6427', '6455', '6456', '6455', '6444', '6452', '6455', '6445', '6452', '6458', '6448', '6428', '6415', '6434', '6432', '6432', '6449', '6435', '6435', '6434', '6425', '6414', '6432', '6445', '6445', '6448', '6438', '6434', '6435', '6448', '6439', '6428', '6448', '6445', '6429', '6432', '6434', '6429', '6435', '6446', '6444', '6424', '6427', '6431', '6429', '6420', '6418', '6417', '6425', '6431', '6431', '6421', '6424', '6441', '6437', '6444', '6442', '6442', '6432', '6446', '6445', '6438', '6461', '6472', '6451', '6437', '6448', '6459', '6459', '6465', '6456', '6441', '6437', '6452', '6441', '6445', '6445', '6435', '6437', '6463', '6485', '6465', '6454', '6469', '6475', '6465', '6478', '6466', '6461', '6463', '6449', '6442', '6451', '6455', '6458', '6461', '6462', '6465', '6461', '6470', '6479', '6468', '6470', '6476', '6475', '6470', '6473', '6475', '6452', '6444', '6452', '6438', '6446', '6448', '6439', '6435', '6456', '6463', '6458', '6461', '6459', '6463', '6472', '6472', '6466', '6461', '6468', '6469', '6466', '6480', '6504', '6521', '6519', '6524', '6533', '6545', '6570', '6570', '6555', '6558', '6558', '6570', '6565', '6562', '6565', '6567', '6581', '6589', '6591', '6608', '6606', '6602', '6605', '6616', '6620', '6623', '6625', '6622', '6601', '6599', '6620', '6622', '6616', '6584', '6565', '6557', '6555', '6529', '6496', '6496', '6485', '6478', '6470', '6452', '6446', '6448', '6446', '6425', '6412', '6405', '6408', '6390', '6384', '6376', '6363', '6370', '6398', '6410', '6420', '6427', '6422', '6410', '6400', '6405', '6400', '6404', '6407', '6398', '6379', '6383', '6390', '6393', '6412', '6412', '6415', '6410', '6424', '6429', '6415', '6404', '6411', '6417', '6424', '6417', '6394', '6388', '6408', '6448', '6517', '6613', '6705', '6790', '6916', '7036', '7140', '7215', '7198', '7095', '7042', '7024', '6881', '6645', '6509', '6410', '6279', '6168', '6132', '6129', '6121', '6121', '6129', '6162', '6209', '6250', '6274', '6295', '6339', '6373', '6398', '6425', '6452', '6444', '6463', '6490', '6495', '6495', '6499', '6500', '6486', '6502', '6517', '6510', '6526', '6531', '6520', '6512', '6512', '6520', '6519', '6519', '6523', '6514', '6533', '6550', '6547', '6547', '6550', '6545', '6541', '6541', '6544', '6538', '6538', '6544', '6545', '6561', '6584', '6588', '6582', '6599', '6609', '6591', '6594', '6606', '6592', '6579', '6588', '6596', '6598', '6611', '6623', '6622', '6633', '6652', '6656', '6646', '6664', '6670', '6642', '6652', '6663', '6660', '6669', '6677', '6677', '6690', '6715', '6711', '6714', '6735', '6751', '6745', '6746', '6763', '6766', '6768', '6782', '6799', '6797', '6804', '6826', '6838', '6848', '6854', '6861', '6872', '6888', '6884', '6878', '6895', '6918', '6908', '6913', '6918', '6925', '6933', '6926', '6913', '6930', '6929', '6918', '6901', '6896', '6891', '6885', '6879', '6887', '6881', '6872', '6872', '6872', '6847', '6836', '6845', '6828', '6813', '6797', '6778', '6755', '6732', '6721', '6704', '6695', '6687', '6653', '6639', '6642', '6629', '6613', '6612', '6615', '6596', '6584', '6585', '6574', '6561', '6564', '6560', '6545', '6540', '6543', '6533', '6529', '6537', '6521', '6507', '6519', '6517', '6506', '6507', '6510', '6500', '6497', '6507', '6514', '6514', '6523', '6519', '6507', '6509', '6521', '6506', '6507', '6519', '6504', '6492', '6510', '6507', '6507', '6514', '6521', '6520', '6530', '6540', '6524', '6514', '6534', '6531', '6499', '6504', '6513', '6509', '6510', '6502', '6497', '6489', '6504', '6516', '6517', '6504', '6509', '6493', '6492', '6502', '6496', '6496', '6512', '6490', '6479', '6486', '6499', '6495', '6495', '6499', '6495', '6482', '6489', '6487', '6496', '6503', '6496', '6478', '6480', '6483', '6476', '6469', '6472', '6469', '6461', '6461', '6463', '6456', '6461', '6463', '6462', '6452', '6461', '6468', '6458', '6441', '6442', '6445', '6451', '6461', '6452', '6446', '6446', '6448', '6441', '6445', '6459', '6442', '6431', '6439', '6434', '6439', '6446', '6437', '6428', '6438', '6449', '6439', '6435', '6445', '6437', '6429', '6445', '6448', '6442', '6444', '6454', '6432', '6424', '6445', '6442', '6415', '6420', '6411', '6410', '6418', '6427', '6417', '6424', '6434', '6429', '6424', '6434', '6441', '6429', '6429', '6435', '6424', '6417', '6434', '6435', '6418', '6445', '6449', '6441', '6444', '6442', '6424', '6424', '6432', '6424', '6414', '6408', '6417', '6415', '6410', '6435', '6432', '6454', '6466', '6472', '6476', '6500', '6510', '6507', '6510', '6516', '6510', '6512', '6523', '6531', '6523', '6540', '6547', '6554', '6562', '6574', '6567', '6562', '6584', '6589', '6570', '6560', '6550', '6548', '6544', '6564', '6562', '6558', '6553', '6533', '6510', '6513', '6510', '6483', '6458', '6459', '6445', '6428', '6418', '6425', '6422', '6427', '6434', '6417', '6408', '6405', '6387', '6366', '6369', '6360', '6342', '6360', '6369', '6364', '6364', '6387', '6379', '6369', '6377', '6383', '6383', '6371', '6360', '6354', '6362', '6369', '6360', '6370', '6377', '6373', '6364', '6379', '6387', '6381', '6377', '6371', '6376', '6403', '6414', '6405', '6383', '6381', '6418', '6468', '6538', '6646', '6722', '6827', '6939', '7041', '7145', '7233', '7242', '7113', '7027', '6997', '6830', '6596', '6444', '6332', '6196', '6088', '6032', '6018', '6033', '6052', '6067', '6108', '6179', '6219', '6224', '6267', '6318', '6352', '6370', '6388', '6393', '6403', '6421', '6425', '6437', '6451', '6461', '6455', '6445', '6459', '6466', '6482', '6499', '6497', '6485', '6480', '6479', '6468', '6473', '6487', '6478', '6490', '6507', '6506', '6502', '6513', '6514', '6514', '6507', '6502', '6497', '6497', '6499', '6495', '6492', '6513', '6527', '6523', '6534', '6541', '6537', '6548', '6554', '6536', '6510', '6517', '6534', '6533', '6506', '6517', '6523', '6541', '6543', '6553', '6560', '6574', '6572', '6570', '6577', '6581', '6571', '6572', '6587', '6581', '6572', '6594', '6615', '6616', '6609', '6626', '6632', '6639', '6659', '6667', '6647', '6654', '6681', '6681', '6688', '6703', '6701', '6710', '6722', '6727', '6734', '6746', '6753', '6753', '6761', '6769', '6773', '6770', '6768', '6769', '6775', '6783', '6775', '6761', '6756', '6768', '6751', '6755', '6761', '6761', '6741', '6739', '6739', '6731', '6729', '6735', '6722', '6704', '6704', '6701', '6691', '6684', '6659', '6640', '6637', '6633', '6599', '6575', '6557', '6543', '6527', '6516', '6504', '6486', '6478', '6480', '6473', '6456', '6458', '6452', '6438', '6444', '6434', '6400', '6391', '6404', '6391', '6379', '6370', '6363', '6364', '6373', '6370', '6364', '6362', '6370', '6371', '6370', '6384', '6379', '6357', '6364', '6381', '6369', '6356', '6369', '6369', '6366', '6367', '6360', '6362', '6386', '6393', '6381', '6371', '6377', '6379', '6377', '6383', '6373', '6357', '6364', '6376', '6380', '6362', '6377', '6383', '6388', '6400', '6401', '6373', '6383', '6407', '6404', '6400', '6400', '6383', '6398', '6407', '6410', '6394', '6397', '6408', '6407', '6401', '6394', '6390', '6401', '6414', '6404', '6393', '6408', '6420', '6408', '6407', '6407', '6398', '6407', '6408', '6405', '6394', '6401', '6405', '6404', '6400', '6410', '6405', '6401', '6408', '6414', '6397', '6397', '6396', '6398', '6400', '6408', '6410', '6407', '6412', '6424', '6421', '6422', '6411', '6414', '6412', '6420', '6407', '6408', '6412', '6412', '6401', '6407', '6412', '6417', '6420', '6424', '6410', '6417', '6422', '6410', '6393', '6412', '6425', '6407', '6403', '6412', '6408', '6405', '6407', '6414', '6410', '6420', '6429', '6415', '6410', '6412', '6408', '6412', '6421', '6410', '6408', '6418', '6412', '6401', '6398', '6410', '6405', '6398', '6411', '6412', '6401', '6407', '6412', '6412', '6417', '6425', '6412', '6418', '6428', '6429', '6412', '6417', '6420', '6420', '6425', '6427', '6418', '6414', '6415', '6415', '6412', '6421', '6424', '6417', '6420', '6449', '6466', '6469', '6478', '6500', '6506', '6523', '6536', '6531', '6541', '6554', '6545', '6533', '6537', '6534', '6538', '6558', '6572', '6562', '6572', '6585', '6578', '6582', '6595', '6615', '6604', '6602', '6596', '6589', '6585', '6595', '6608', '6612', '6605', '6589', '6571', '6575', '6558', '6541', '6529', '6519', '6504', '6499', '6495', '6495', '6480', '6482', '6483', '6478', '6485', '6485', '6452', '6437', '6439', '6435', '6431', '6444', '6458', '6465', '6469', '6479', '6482', '6476', '6489', '6496', '6475', '6470', '6475', '6472', '6478', '6478', '6469', '6475', '6492', '6516', '6503', '6510', '6523', '6514', '6513', '6516', '6503', '6512', '6537', '6538', '6513', '6502', '6512', '6555', '6612', '6711', '6802', '6885', '7003', '7107', '7205', '7308', '7368', '7303', '7178', '7136', '7070', '6862', '6663', '6540', '6415', '6288', '6203', '6176', '6189', '6210', '6214', '6238', '6287', '6333', '6371', '6414', '6459', '6485', '6506', '6521', '6526', '6553', '6570', '6577', '6585', '6588', '6588', '6591', '6591', '6609', '6616', '6620', '6629', '6636', '6622', '6625', '6611', '6598', '6587', '6594', '6592', '6599', '6596', '6606', '6613', '6630', '6647', '6640', '6646', '6652', '6629', '6616', '6625', '6625', '6622', '6640', '6643', '6650', '6639', '6647', '6660', '6669', '6669', '6666', '6646', '6637', '6650', '6636', '6639', '6662', '6654', '6656', '6677', '6694', '6688', '6701', '6714', '6712', '6708', '6722', '6722', '6722', '6728', '6729', '6731', '6744', '6749', '6755', '6765', '6792', '6795', '6778', '6790', '6807', '6809', '6799', '6814', '6824', '6819', '6830', '6850', '6864', '6872', '6891', '6887', '6902', '6929', '6928', '6923', '6929', '6939', '6937', '6937', '6940', '6939', '6959', '6966', '6959', '6957', '6963', '6952', '6953', '6970', '6980', '6969', '6956', '6969', '6969', '6973', '6974', '6970', '6962', '6947', '6936', '6911', '6887', '6882', '6870', '6847', '6840', '6820', '6799', '6790', '6792', '6779', '6769', '6753', '6738', '6722', '6712', '6701', '6691', '6681', '6683', '6671', '6666', '6660', '6643', '6652', '6652', '6640', '6622', '6613', '6623', '6623', '6620', '6609', '6618', '6620', '6623', '6628', '6618', '6620', '6625', '6619', '6616', '6626', '6633', '6632', '6635', '6633', '6636', '6650', '6663', '6653', '6647', '6643', '6639', '6646', '6654', '6662', '6652', '6656', '6667', '6660', '6663', '6673', '6660', '6652', '6663', '6662', '6642', '6640', '6650', '6645', '6653', '6676', '6673', '6657', '6667', '6670', '6676', '6686', '6679', '6653', '6656', '6664', '6650', '6652', '6656', '6650', '6643', '6645', '6649', '6646', '6649', '6653', '6645', '6662', '6662', '6650', '6643', '6649', '6653', '6657', '6662', '6664', '6654', '6652', '6650', '6659', '6659', '6662', '6666', '6662', '6659', '6656', '6654', '6646', '6663', '6659', '6649', '6652', '6652', '6647', '6636', '6646', '6649', '6642', '6643', '6647', '6636', '6636', '6632', '6629', '6629', '6646', '6632', '6622', '6620', '6625', '6628', '6629', '6637', '6633', '6635', '6637', '6633', '6640', '6637', '6636', '6646', '6637', '6625', '6620', '6626', '6628', '6629', '6619', '6630', '6642', '6639', '6637', '6645', '6628', '6625', '6645', '6643', '6632', '6626', '6625', '6622', '6633', '6635', '6623', '6626', '6632', '6629', '6626', '6632', '6637', '6622', '6633', '6642', '6640', '6647', '6654', '6652', '6635', '6646', '6656', '6646', '6649', '6652', '6640', '6630', '6647', '6662', '6669', '6659', '6652', '6667', '6686', '6704', '6722', '6720', '6720', '6738', '6748', '6762', '6759', '6746', '6755', '6761', '6758', '6766', '6780', '6792', '6793', '6806', '6820', '6816', '6830', '6837', '6821', '6816', '6804', '6802', '6800', '6804', '6796', '6790', '6786', '6785', '6779', '6769', '6758', '6732', '6717', '6714', '6693', '6666', '6660', '6676', '6653', '6649', '6664', '6666', '6663', '6657', '6653', '6636', '6636', '6642', '6625', '6608', '6616', '6615', '6623', '6633', '6646', '6649', '6649', '6650', '6643', '6642', '6649', '6639', '6630', '6633', '6630', '6640', '6654', '6660', '6657', '6656', '6663', '6676', '6674', '6671', '6669', '6650', '6650', '6659', '6663', '6669', '6663', '6659', '6680', '6746', '6819', '6901', '6988', '7097', '7198', '7295', '7416', '7469', '7438', '7338', '7261', '7218', '7073', '6855', '6700', '6604', '6500', '6398', '6337', '6339', '6370', '6371', '6380', '6432', '6487', '6499', '6523', '6548', '6584', '6637', '6659', '6676', '6694', '6704', '6707', '6708', '6732', '6728', '6717', '6724', '6725', '6727', '6737', '6744', '6746', '6745', '6772', '6778', '6772', '6763', '6751', '6734', '6745', '6755', '6756', '6753', '6765', '6756', '6739', '6739', '6741', '6744', '6763', '6772', '6756', '6752', '6775', '6783', '6773', '6780', '6787', '6768', '6768', '6768', '6755', '6751', '6738', '6751', '6758', '6765', '6780', '6770', '6786', '6816', '6810', '6812', '6826', '6816', '6793', '6800', '6809', '6789', '6782', '6802', '6807', '6802', '6812', '6824', '6850', '6884', '6896', '6878', '6874', '6885', '6887', '6879', '6889', '6906', '6895', '6895', '6906', '6922', '6943', '6962', '6970', '6977', '6987', '6978', '6984', '6988', '6984', '6971', '6970', '6978', '6976', '6978', '6981', '6978', '6974', '6988', '7010', '7010', '7000', '6997', '6988', '6981', '6987', '6969', '6953', '6959', '6953', '6935', '6935', '6930', '6902', '6889', '6895', '6879', '6853', '6833', '6809', '6782', '6762', '6755', '6739', '6722', '6728', '6710', '6697', '6687', '6686', '6666', '6660', '6656', '6643', '6642', '6636', '6611', '6602', '6599', '6596', '6596', '6594', '6584', '6581', '6588', '6589', '6582', '6579', '6578', '6591', '6592', '6591', '6578', '6562', '6555', '6575', '6577', '6561', '6555', '6555', '6553', '6565', '6579', '6570', '6561', '6564', '6568', '6561', '6587', '6592', '6577', '6575', '6594']
```

Here [7237, 7288, 7215, 7242, 7368, 7469] these are the peak/high elements.

I need to find:

```
Q=(lowest value on left of each peak/high element)
S=(lowest value on the right of each peak/high element)
```

My program so far (finding high peaks):

```
lead_2=['#Those values']
print (lead_2)
lead_2 = list(map(int, lead_2))
idx = range(len(lead_2))
pval = [1 - sum([i >= j for j in lead_2]) / (len(lead_2)+1) for i in lead_2]
stat_pval = [idx for idx,p in enumerate(pval) if p <= 0.01]
grps = []
consec_idx = []
stat_pval.append(stat_pval[-1]+2)

for i in range(len(stat_pval)-1):
    if stat_pval[i] == stat_pval[i+1]-1:
        consec_idx.append(stat_pval[i])
    else:
        consec_idx.append(stat_pval[i])
        grps.append(consec_idx)
        consec_idx = []
del consec_idx
del stat_pval[-1]
idx_and_max_per_peak = []
Peak_value=[max(lead_2[grp[0]:grp[-1]+1]) for grp in grps]
print ('HighestPeak_value=',Peak_value)
```

Example method

let's take

```
A=['22','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','27','24','15','23','22','32','30','28','20','27','17','22','28','42','40','35','22','16']
```

here peaks are (28,32,42), I need the values that are low before and after each peak.

like

- B=21,22,17 # lows in left of each peak
- C=15,20,16 # lows in right of each peak

Comment: what makes a number a peak, because by your logic many more numbers could be peaks

Comment: Yeah that's 20, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zip() function is very useful when you are looking for patterns of relative values within a list.  It allows you to obtain pairings (or triples) of values that are next to each other.

```
def findHighPeaks(A,count):
    # positions of values that are top of hills or bottom of valleys
    pivots   = [i for a,(i,b),c in zip(A,enumerate(A[1:],1),A[2:])
                                if a>b and b<c or a<b and b>c]

    # merge pivot positions into triples
    # representing the low-high-low or high-low-high indexes
    iWaves = [(left,mid,right) for left,mid,right
                               in  zip([0]+pivots,pivots,pivots[1:]+[len(A)-1])]
    
    # extract only peak values from patterns of hills and valleys
    peaks  = [(A[left],A[mid],A[right]) for left,mid,right in iWaves
                                        if A[left]<A[mid]]

    # find the highest peaks, and put them in a set
    highPeaks = set(sorted(peaks,key=lambda p:p[1])[-count:])

    # Return high peaks, in original order
    return [p for p in peaks if p in highPeaks]

# A = big list
    
Q,R,S = zip(*findHighPeaks(A,6)) # large example
print(R) # (7237, 7288, 7215, 7242, 7368, 7469) peaks
print(Q) # (6420, 6475, 6388, 6381, 6502, 6659) Low on the left
print(S) # (6076, 6180, 6452, 6018, 6176, 6337) Low on the right

A = ['22','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','27','24','15','23',
   '22','32','30','28','20','27','17','22','28','42','40','35','22','16']

Q,R,S = zip(*findHighPeaks(A,3)) # small example
print(R) # ('28', '32', '42') peaks
print(Q) # ('21', '22', '17') Low on the left
print(S) # ('15', '20', '16') Low on the right
```

Here is a visual representation of the selection process, which is based on relative variations (increasing/decreasing).

```
                                  HI                                        
                                 '28'                                   
                              '27'  '27'      HI    HI                     HI   
                           '26'        '24'  '23'  '32'                   '42'
                       '25'               '15'  '22'  '30'     HI      '28'  '40'
                    '24'                   LO    LO     '28'  '27'  '22'        '35'  
                 '23'                                      '20'  '17'              '22' 
        '22'  '22'                                          LO    LO                  '16'
           '21'
            LO

peaks:                           28           23    32         27          42       
            ||-------------------^^-------||--^^-||-^^------||-^^-||-------^^----------||
left:       21                            15     22         20    17
right:                                    15     22         20    17                   16
```

Comment: hi @Aloan T. your answer was quite helpful. the prob is I need to find the extreme peaks and their lows to their left and right. i.e I should return the value from which the next value should increase

Comment: I tried this program with that huge data, it prints all the lows. I need the lowest of em all. for every peak, there should be two lows (right and left)

Comment: The program already provides all the lowest preceding and subsequent value.  It does so in separate variables as requested (although tuples would be much easier to deal with).  You will have to describe what makes peaks the highest for you because you excluded a bunch of peaks in your examples but did not explain why all the others would be excluded.

Comment: Actually those original values are of ecg data. R is the highest peak of em. With reference to the R-peak I have to find the Q and S . Which is left and right to the Highest peak R.

Comment: We had to exclude the other peaks. Because they may occur due to noise. R is the peak element.

Comment: What is your criteria to decide that a peak is "noise"?  Do you need to have at least X number of samples between the two low points? I noticed that the two peaks you are excluding (23 and 27) are very narrow.  Is that your condition to exclude them ?

Comment: Yeah, I have identified the peak by using my program in the question, the highest value that by comparing with nearby value is the peak. May be like u said. I need to find the nearby lowest value that is in  right and left of each peak

Comment: I edited my response to make it clearer. Hoping it will help.

Comment: @Alian T . Your answer was absolutely correct regarding to my examples. But at my original values at the top. I had to take the highest among the peak. i.e the values above 6,800. These are ecg data. The Highest peak is the R-peak. The lowest peak that I need to find is the Q and S peak. Since in an ECG , the R peak is the only thing that has the highest peak amongst the other. Since we neglect the rest of em.

Comment: Am I to understand that the Q peak is the highest peak preceding R and the S peak is the highest peak following R?  In that case, there would not be a S peak in the small example and the peak value 28 should not be there.

Comment: No, Q is the lowest peak from where the R starts when reaches the maximum it again get reduced to form S lowest peak.

Comment: Hi @Alian, How to find the index of each element FROM Q,R,S